# How do I switch to the dev channel of Google Chrome under Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I have Chrome in Windows set to dev channel easily using the Chrome Channel Changer too. However, I can't find a similar tool or any straightforward instructions to switch the channels for the Mac version. I'm currently running the stable channel and I want to switch to dev. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely similar to what you did last time if not the same; here's how: Hop over to [this page](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel), and click on "Dev Channel" (or Canary if you're into that stuff), download the new .dmg, and you're up and running on the dev channel of Chrome.